Is every thing in life predetermined?
Is every thing in life predetermined ? I ask this question as , my mother wants to say that even if I work hard I will still not be as good as other good students are in their domain. I always work hard but fail, which I know that I have many faults with me but no one is there to give me experience that I am doing something wrong. Even though I try I fail all the time and donot get the right thinga at the right time . I feel so frustrated that what is the point of dreaming anything big if always I am destined to be lesser than others . Some people will think I should be myself but in the real world only the very best get the attention, complements etc. Even I like that but only I am predestined to not get that then will I not get it even with my hard work ? Why god does this to me ?

Simple math: only 10 can be the best 10.

What do you mean @GyroGearloose
